# How to set connection string database TDE with certificate provide

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a local database with the certificate to protect the security of a database. I try using this normal connection string to connect, it failed due this database had set on security. How do I connect this database from C# if in the application provide certificate and password as well?
our connection string now.

```
global.ConnString = String.Format(@"Server=(localdb)\v11.0;AttachDbFileName={0}\TestTDE\{1};Integrated Security=SSPI;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Packet Size=4096", Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments), "TDETesting.mdf");
```

Comment: The "T" in "TDE" stands for "transparent". Meaning that once the database is mounted to the server, clients trying to access the database don't need to do anything special. What error are you getting when you try to connect?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the username="username you use to connect to database" password="its password" inside your connection string. try removing Integrated security